# Add a spacer line between layouts PyQt

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4

I would like to add a spacer line between two layouts:

```
Separador = QFrame()
Separador.Shape(QFrame.HLine)
Separador.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Minimum,QSizePolicy.Expanding)
Separador.setLineWidth(3)
HPOUT1_layout = QVBoxLayout()
HPOUT1_layout.addLayout(HPOUT1L_layout)
HPOUT1_layout.addWidget(Separador)
HPOUT1_layout.addLayout(HPOUT1R_layout)
```

However, this code only separate the layouts a little, but there is no line visible between them. 
Is there another way, What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are not setting the shape of the frame correctly.

Instead of

```
Separador.Shape(QFrame.HLine)
```

use

```
Separador.setFrameShape(QFrame.HLine)
```

Comment: It Worked, but I also had to comment this line:
`Separador.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Minimum,QSizePolicy.Expanding)`